# Custom MapRoute

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-routing, maproute

I am attempting to create some custom map routes but can't get it working quite right.

My ultimate aim is to be able to specify something like the following. Where by I essentially have my URL constructed with value pairs of "id" and "name".  The name is irrelevant and solely for user pleasantries, I will require the ID in my controller though.

> /dashboards/5-My-Estate-name/89-My-subgroup-name/133-Maybe-even-another-subgroup

For starters I'm working on the first section and having troubles.

Browsing to "http://localhost:53933/dashboards/109-building-xyz" whilst using the following route generates the error `A public action method '109-building-xyz' was not found on controller 'MyInterfaceInterface.Controllers.DashboardsController'.`

```
routes.MapRoute(
  "Dashboard",
  "dashboards/{id}-{name}", // URL pattern
   new { controller = "Dashboards", action = "Index" },
   new { id = @"\d+", name = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

Obviously I wanted this to be routed to the Index function with parameters.

What am I doing wrong? Am I even structuring this correctly? I come from a web-PHP background and using htaccess to achieve such things.

Thanks

Comment: Did you add this after the default route, or before it?

Comment: I think you can only separate parameters using a forward slash (but might be mistaken on this). If the dash is accepted as a separator it's likely that you will need to include the dash after the id to make the route work though. Also, as Chris hints at, route ordering is important. I'd recommend using NuGet to install the RouteDebugger package (and enable it in Web.config). It allows you to easily find out what route any given URL matches.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The order of routes matter. MVC will match the first declared route with a pattern that matches the URL pattern.

So if you have this:

```
routes.MapRoute(
  "Default",
  "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL pattern
   new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" },
   new { id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
routes.MapRoute(
  "Dashboard",
  "dashboards/{id}-{name}", // URL pattern
   new { controller = "Dashboards", action = "Index" },
   new { id = @"\d+", name = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

Then what will happen with the URL `http://localhost:53933/dashboards/109-building-xyz` is that MVC will match "dashboards" to the controller and "109-building-xyz" to the action.

You need to always declare your most specific routes first, and more general routes afterward, like so:

```
routes.MapRoute(
  "Dashboard",
  "dashboards/{id}-{name}", // URL pattern
   new { controller = "Dashboards", action = "Index" },
   new { id = @"\d+", name = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
routes.MapRoute(
  "Default",
  "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL pattern
   new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" },
   new { id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

However, Morten Mertner is right in his comment -- I don't think you can have 2 route parameters that are not separated by a forward slash. You would need to change your URL pattern to something like this in order to use it with the default routing engine:

```
"dashboards/{id}/{name}"
```